# Not capitalized "Figure" in latex

Tags: captions, labels

I am trying to use "**Fig.**" when naming my figures, I tried so many things but nothing seems to work. Currently I have this:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf}
```

which gives me "**FIG.**", but I can't seem to get it to lowercase. Can someone tell me what to do please? Thank you!

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: Please, add a small example of code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that shows the behavior. Quite likely, it's the document class that sets `\figurename` to “FIG.”, but it's impossible to help if you don't tell which one it is.

Comment: Your code fragment doesn't produce showed result. It is **Figure:**.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
        justification=raggedright,
        singlelinecheck=false,
        labelfont=bf,
        name=Fig.}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Mr. Duck, LaTeX full professor.}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
The `caption` package offer may options for determining styles. All are concise described in its documentation, which is part of your LaTeX installation or you can find it on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption?lang=en).

From your comment I guess, that you like only change the caption label in its default settings.

**Edit:** Apparently my guessing was wrong, as OP say in her/his next comments. Since meaning #left-right# aligning is still not clarified, I further quess, that probably should be something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{
        singlelinecheck=false,
        labelfont=bf,    
        name=Fig.}       
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{Mrs. Duck, Quin of LaTeX.}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\caption{\lipsum[66]}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One quick question, right now the text in the captions is right-aligned, but I want it left-right aligned. How can i fix that?

Comment: @JohnDoe122, you mean justified? In this case just remove the first two options in caption settings (see addendum to answer). All option for caption styles are described in the package documentation. It is worth for reading it.

Comment: if I remove the first 2 options the caption becomes centered, instead of left-right aligned. Did you do anything else on top of that?

Comment: @JohnDoe122, do you look addendum to answer? BTW, your "left-right aligned" request is unclear. Provide a sketch, what you mean with this. Apparently my guessing in addendum is wrong ...

Comment: by left-right I mean what you show in Fig. 2. however, just removing the 2 options in the original post doesn't work for me

Comment: @JohnDoe122, I do not understand you.  Please provide a sketch what you after.  Short text can not be "left-right" aligned. If you mean, that short text should start at lef text border, than add `singlelinecheck=false`  to caption options.

Comment: @JohnDoe122, why you retract acceptance of answer? In my answer solve your problem stated in your question and also try to further help you as you ask in comment(s). I'm sorry that you are not willing to help me understand, what you like to to be additional solved and was not mentioned in question. Actually, if you have new problem, please ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{mylabel}{\textbf{Fig.}\textbf{#2}}

\usepackage{tikz} % <-- to create a square image (just use your image)

\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,labelfont=bf,labelformat=mylabel}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{A square}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It works for me and gives me the above output. Is that you want in the output, or I didn't understand what exactly you want?